# git log --pretty=oneline on win xp cmd

Tags: git, cmd

I just recently noticed this behaviour. To put it shortly, it displays the commits with an END on a white background, and gets stuck.

Upon pressing "q" it asks if I wish to terminate the batch job ?

Is anyone else experiencing this ? Is this a known bug, or ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `END` on a white background comes from `less` through which the output is being piped.

I have recently noticed odd crashes using Cygwin utilities from the command line but have not had a chance to investigate yet.

Comment: I see. That means it's one of those git/cmd things ... not going to be fixed anytime soon :) In any case, good to know. Thanks.